# How to execute SQL query that contains "from" and "to" as table column names?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a script to import some data from our database to a MySQL based webshop platform.
Unfortunately, in the table that I need to input some data, the developers of the webshop named two columns "from" and "to", which throws an syntax error when I try to execute my query. This is what I want to do:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (
                from,
                to)
                VALUES (
                'some value',
                'some value'
                )";
```

I'm no SQL crack, so I'm wondering if there is a way to execute the query even if the columns are named "from" and "to"? Is there maybe a way to escape "from" and "to" in the query?

Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: Ideally you should rename those columns with a prefix as it is bad practice to use keywords

Comment: surround the identifier with backticks

Comment: `from` and `to` are [Reserved Keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-F). You should really avoid using these as field/table name(s). Else use backticks around them

Comment: 'Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as described in Section 9.2, “Schema Object Names”:' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html Whoever created the table must have known that,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go. put the names into `` ` ``

```
insert into tab(`from`,`to`) values ('some value', 'some value');
```

> ```
> select * from tab;
> ```
>
> ```
> from       | to        
> :--------- | :---------
> some value | some value
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e81c7f199f051b2bb6ef65874b6fb5bb)*

> **BUT: you should never use [RESERVED keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) as names**